# Template binding in Titanium Alloy without models and collections?

Tags: data-binding, templating, titanium-alloy

I have a long list of static data I want to bind (in this case, a list of countries, and states/provinces) to a "drop down" list.

Since this is static data, using models and collections not only seems like overkill, but in my experimenting, is also REALLY slow with this much data.

What I'd like to do is a simple template binding, without having to mess with models and collections. Just take an array of objects, and loop over it, binding the necessary XML in my view.

Given the fact that there are so many JS templating engines, I assumed this would be possible in Titanium? My searching has turned up nothing helpful.

Comment: I realize I can just use a good ole fashioned "factory" and just create elements programatically in my controller, just wondering if there's something more slick (like a templating option).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a listView with the appropriate configuration of the ItemTemplate and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Data binding in Alloy is tightly coupled to Backbone model and collection objects.  When you declare a `dataCollection` attribute on an element in an Alloy view XML file, the code generator creates a loop that runs though the collection specified by that attribute, constructing a new view object for each model in the collection and setting the appropriate properties of the view and its subviews.  You can see how this works by opening the generated code under the `Resources` folder in your project.

Looping through a Backbone collection should not be much slower than going through a plain array, so I am guessing that the poor performance you were seeing was because you were loading the collection using one of the [persistence adapters](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Sync_Adapters_and_Migrations) as shown in the example code and documentation.  If your data isn't going to change at runtime, however, you can create a plain Backbone collection and call that collection's `reset()` method to do a bulk set of your data, avoiding all of the overhead related with obtaining data though a persistence adapter.  Here's an extract from the [Alloy sample app](https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/tree/master/test/apps/models/binding_no_persistence) which shows how this is done:

```
// alloy.js
Alloy.Collections.heroes = new Backbone.Collection();
Alloy.Collections.heroes.reset([
    { name: 'Ironman' },
    { name: 'Superman' },
    { name: 'Thor' },
    { name: 'Captain America' },
    { name: 'Hulk' },
    { name: 'Green Lantern' },
    { name: 'Punisher' },
    { name: 'Spiderman' },
    { name: 'Wolverine' },
    { name: 'Cyclops' }
]);
```

Once the collection has been created, it can be bound to views:

```
<TableView dataCollection="heroes">
  <TableViewRow title="{name}"/>
</TableView>
```

Take a look at the Alloy repo on Github for examples that show how to bind to various collection views:  https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy.